# Does Kittens Game have an end?

Tags: kittens-game

I play Kittens Game a lot recently, mostly side-by-side to Arqade or other SE sites. I got far; I am at year 400 (background tab farming) and got tons of titanium, unobtanium and whatnot. I wondered if there is an end in Kittens game, or the game just keeps going on, even after all has been researched and crafted (something like Zombie HQ).

Is there an end? Also, what is the last technology to be discovered/researched?

Comment: Sounds like an Idle game, which basically means there is no end. You just keep getting higher and higher. Then you give up everything to restart, but with a bonus/boost that lets you go farther than before at a faster rate, all to just do it again but get an even bigger bonus. Even when you get everything, you can still keep going, if only for the bragging rights of saying you have thousands of zeros after the number that is your currency. (Or leader board positions)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no end to Kittens Game.

Some of the far off things to achieve in the game include the **Cathammer 40k** achievement, requiring you to play for 40,000 years. So you still have a bit to go.

The Unobtainium you got is actually only the basis to an even rarer resource, **Eludium**. It is extremely expensive to produce and can be used to construct certain space structures and research high-end workshop upgrades. Additionally, it can be used to trade with the **Leviathans**, your most important trading partners during the late-game. They will provide you with resources which are even rarer than eludium and can otherwise only be obtained by massive unicorn production.

To make contact with the leviathans, you need to construct **Markers** and **Black Pyramids**.

Also at later stages of the game, **Religion** plays a huge part, as it grants you extensive production bonuses. You will *reset* your faith counter often to get a praying bonus, which will lead you to accumulate even more faith and larger bonuses. This is known as the **Apocrypha** bonus.
Even further, you can sacrifice your apocrypha bonus, by **transcending**, which is a technology researched late in the game. This opens up even more advanced religion upgrades.

In addition to that, you have the normal game resets, which grant you additional **Paragon** (among other bonuses). These can be spent on **Metaphysics** upgrades, some of which are required to open up technology paths otherwise unavailable by non-reset gameplay (as you only earn paragon at a very low rate, 1 paragon every 1,000 years). This will enable you to build the markers and black pyramids mentioned earlier.

Beyond that, there are extremely expensive technologies which currently have no purpose. Their purpose is still to be decided and will be added in later updates to the game; these technologies include **Thorium** and **Terraforming**.

It is my understanding that current development focuses on giving more purpose to the **Darkmatter** resource, a resource that was only recently added to the game.